# Is there a way to search terms in order with RegexpQuery in lucene?

Tags: regex, lucene

I would like to search my indexed documents in order using RegexpQuery.

For example I have 2 Document
text: Oracle unveils better than expected quarterly results.
text: Research In Motion shares gained almost 13 per cent on the Toronto Stock Exchange Friday, a day after the smartphone maker posted better than expected quarterly results.

So far I tried this but I got no luck.

Query regexq = new RegexpQuery(new Term("text", "^.+better.+quarterly.+results"));

Is there another way of implementing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe a [`PhraseQuery`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/PhraseQuery.html) fits what you are looking for better.  You can use `PhraseQuery.setSlop(int)` to allow terms to appear between the terms of the query.  This would like like:

```
Query pq = new PhraseQuery();
pq.add(new Term("text", "better"));
pq.add(new Term("text", "quarterly"));
pq.add(new Term("text", "results"));
pq.setSlop(10);  //Or whatever is an appropriate slop value for you.
```

This sort of query is also supported by the standard QueryParser, [as seen here](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html#Proximity%20Searches), like:

```
text:"better quarterly results"~10
```

---

I think a PhraseQuery is most definitely the better implementation here, but...

Regarding [RegexpQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/RegexpQuery.html):

I believe it is intended to compare terms against the regex, and since the phrase you are searching for (I am assuming) is tokenized, no single Term matches your whole regex.  You would need to index the entire field as a single Term to make this work, using `StringField`, `KeywordAnalyzer`, or similar.

I believe it works like `Matcher.matches()`, rather than `Matcher.find()`, which is to say, it must match the entire input term, rather than a portion of it.  So, if you had specified "text" as a [StringField](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/StringField.html), you would need to add a `.*` to the end to consume the rest of the input.

On a similar note, I'm not sure if it supports the use of the character "`^`" as the start of input, being that it is redundant in that case.  I don't see it specified in [Lucene's Regexp](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/util/automaton/RegExp.html), but I have seen reference to it's use, so I'm not sure whether it would be accepted or not.

To summarize, a `RegexpQuery` could work like:

```
Query regexq = new RegexpQuery(new Term("text", ".+better.+quarterly.+results.*"));
```

If you used a `StringField`, or `KeywordAnalyzer` index the entire field as a single Term.

With the leading wildcard in your regexp, though, you could expect very poor performance from it (See the warning at the top of the [RegexpQuery documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/RegexpQuery.html)).

Comment: I did however use PhraseQuery before but the search result terms didn't stay in the order. I ended up adding SpanTermQuery and SpanNearQuery to BooleanQuery.